# What's the best to do when you need a verb using REST api?

Tags: rest

I'm exposing a REST API, and It's amazingly easy and smooth to work with as long as you do CRUD (Create, Update, Delete). But I have this Tickets which return a list of tickets (get), a Ticket/{id} which get a particular item (get) and an activate method (put) that change the ticket status from not activated to activated.

Now I'm in need to give the REST 'consumer' the ability to do something like (in ws will be called: GetAndActivateRandomTicket() and it keeps me wondering, what that should be described as on REST ? Is it a post? A put? A get? The Goal is to get a random amount of tickets and set their status to active. Something like a get & put at the same time but without knowing before hand the {id} for the put.

Should it be /Tickets?activate=true&amount=5 ? What verb? Should I expose a verb instead of a noun? What is the 'best practices' on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted this :

> Anything can be made a resource including transactions, sessions and other such non-domain entities :)

and went with :

TicketActivation resource.

[POST] with a query parameter of amount will return a set of random tickets activated.
and return the resource url as such that you can get like /ticket/id=1,2,3,4,5
[GET] will return tickets as normaly with an optional filter of id to return multiple tickets
[PUT] will use the filter of id also and set activation true or false depending on parameter.

so I can do :

```
[post]
/ticket/activation/?amount=5
```

resource returned will be something like /ticket?id=1,2,3,4,5
so I can issue a get on it.

```
[get]
/ticket?id=1,2,3,4,5

[put]
/ticket/activation?id=1,2,3,4,5&deActivate [OR]
/ticket/activation?id=1,2,3,4,5&activate
```

I guess this is the most elegant and also RESTfull and clear solution to this problem, I wanted to share for future reference. Also if you think there is a problem with this approach feel free to comment on it.

Answer (score 4):

If repeating the operation does something different (e.g., activates a different ticket) then it is **not idempotent**. Non-idempotent operations *always* map to POST (or a custom verb) in a RESTful architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Some resources are easily identifiable and exist in the domain. Some however are a bit tricky as you pointed out. But ROA (resource oriented architecture) takes some getting used to. Anything can be made a resource including transactions, sessions and other such non-domain entities :)

In your case you seem to have an 'algorithmic' resource - selecting a random amount of tickets and activating them. I'm sure this 'randomness' has some way of selecting tickets which is not purely random else there'll be wasted computation with getting already activated set of tickets.

So I'm not sure how your activation is happening - does someone select activate against a bunch of tickets (checkboxes) or just part of 'data packet' without human intervention?

You description seems to hint the latter - so a good practice is to do what you just said: 
Multiple options on the URL:

- /Tickets?amountToActivate=5;activate (Note the semicolon and just the 'word' activate)
- /Tickets?amountToActivate=5&activate=true (Note: I personally feel the above is better since *=true* is actually redundant, it's an artifact of non-restful URIs where most folks would explicitly state = true - it's as good as just writing 'activate' in the URL (implies true) absence would imply false :)

Your resource IS algorithmic and the human 'consumer of the URL' when reading it would instantly understand the former URL, *=true* may not be well understood, but that's just me perhaps. There is a tendency to also use the latter since most frameworks are able to parse query parameters and split by '&' and semicolons may just require some work

In case if there is manual intervention you can break it into two parts:

- GET: /Tickets?fetchRandomAmountOfTickets=100 (since it's algorithmic)
- PUT: /Tickets (the activation 'update' part of PUT for list of tickets that you 'GOT' above)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The activation may happen both ways, one way requesting tickets and then activating 1 or more. That's clear. The other way is that the consumer wants to activate any ticket available (the random is not actually random but a "SELECT ticket FROM Db LIMIT 1") it's just any ticket. So I think the answer would be : /Tickets?amountToActivate=5&activate=true (my personal preference) but with what verb? GET? PUT? POST? If activate is implyed on the URL i think it's a GET, but that goes against REST because it actually DOES change something and that's not the spirit of GET.... 'still confused'

Comment: Aaah! I see. The confusion is with having the resource be modified with the "GET" call - valid point. I overlooked that. Here's what you can do remain true to spirit of Rest :) GET: /Tickets/fetchAmountOfTickets=100&activated=false (or ...100;notActivated) and then send a PUT request with the activation update. I don't see the problem with that. You are filtering the GET w.r.t. some parameters (algorithmic) and then modifying those resources using PUT

Comment: client may want to avoid the get/put and do both with a single request just send me the ticket data and set to activated... :) (without knowing before-hand which one would be activated and returned).

Comment: In that case don't call a GET on /Tickets?amountOfTickets=100&activate=true rather a PUT (it won't be taken as a GET - you are telling the server to update that status of a random amount of tickets and you may get an acknowledgement of Success OK (200) if designed such). I don't see the problem, unless I'm missing something

Comment: I would say in that instance it should use POST (as Donal Fellows mentions) since PUT is idempotent but the operation being described here isn't.

Comment: @laz: I guess PUT is idempotent in this case - if you were to get the same tickets again, reactivating them wouldn't have any effect. The activation itself seems to be idempotent in this context. A PUT would work just fine, unless I'm missing something :)

Comment: Your last comment suggested using a put to tell the server to update the status of a random amount of tickets. Since it is random, it can't be idempotent.

Comment: Ok, post is the way to go. But now, it looks ugly.
I have /Tickets [POST ticket] to create a new ticket
and /Tickets [POST activate&amount=5] to activate 5 tickets and return data.

doesn't look good at all.

Comment: /ticket [post] add new ticket
/ticket/# [get] get ticket #
/activate-ticket/ [post] algorithm resource. change 5 unactivated tickets into activated and returns them.

it's ok to have the amount of tickets on the body or should them be on the uri ?

Comment: Modern browsers don't have a limit on the URI but somehow tend to follow 255 characters at times. I'd go with a body since, the URI is not identifying the resource in that case.

Answer (score 2):

First of all GET should be idempotent and never make any changes to the resource. Activating a resource should be done using a PUT.

What I would do is create a resource URL like /Tickets/Random that as a result to a GET returns an HTTP 303 to redirect the user to a randomly determined actual resource URL like /Tickets/12345. The user can then activate this ticket using a PUT. All the user app needs to know is the /Tickets/Random URL and he can keep on activating tickets as long as there are any there.

Comment: PUT should also be idempotent! If you PUT twice, you should end up with the same result (e.g., always redirect the same user to the same random resource). I prefer to model non-idempotent commits as POSTs.

Comment: The PUT doesn't redirect, the GET does. And its idempotent because it always redirects, although not always to the same resource, and doesn't make any changes to the resource in question. According to your definition you can only use a 303 with a POST while it is normally used with a GET.

Comment: GET shouldn't change state (meaningfully); PUT sets the state, but repeating it twice in a row should result in the same overall thing happening as if it was done once. POSTs, being non-idempotent, can change the state in any way they want. Redirects don't change the state in themselves.

Comment: Agree with @Donal I guess in this case PUT is indeed idempotent - reactivating the same set of tickets over and over again produces the same result. The issue is the aspect of randomness that the OP has put forth...if it's truly (pseudo) random then I guess a POST is better since it could have a mix of random/non-random tickets. But if it's random only on the non-activated set, repeating the operation on the same set is in fact idempotent; unless you change the set :)